# Get image's size name from it's dimension

Tags: php, images

As we know, image's sizes have different names which we can use to call the appropriate image size. Like 'thumbnail', 'large', 'medium' or a custom 'my-thumbnail' size. I can `the_post_thumbnail_url( 'medium' )` to get medium size and it's dimensions.

however, i need to get the NAME from the image size. To be precise, if the image size is 300x200 and it's name is 'small', i want to get 'small' by entering 300 and 200 into a function.

Can anyone help me achieve this please?
Thanks.

Comment: It's possible, depending on the image sizes that several themes or plugins may create, for an image file to match more than one image size.  If you have `medium` set to 300x300 and `medium-crop` set to 300x200 with hard crop then an uploaded image of 600x400 will use the same 300x200 image for both of these sizes.  What result would you prefer from your function in that case?

Comment: I just have thumbnail, medium and another custom 'my-thumbnail' size. i would like to get image's dimension and check whether if it's one of these sizes or not.

Comment: And are you starting with the filename?

Comment: no i just have 2 integers (width & heigh) and want the size name. thanks for the time, the code provided by @the_dramatist is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've written a function for you. Place this below function on your `functions.php` or any where that executes and pass the width and height value to it. It will return you the image size name as `string` and if it has not found any then it will return `false`.

```
/**
 * Get name by size information for image.
 *
 * @global $_wp_additional_image_sizes
 * @uses   get_intermediate_image_sizes()
 * @return string $_sizes bool Data for passed measurements image.
 */
function wpse_243461_get_image_size_name( $w = 150, $h = 150 ) {
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $sizes = array();
    foreach ( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $_size ) {
        if ( in_array( $_size, array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'medium_large', 'large') ) ) {
            if ( $w == get_option( "{$_size}_size_w" ) && $h == get_option( "{$_size}_size_h" ))
                return $_size;
        } elseif ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ] ) ) {
            if ( $w == $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ]['width'] && $h == $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ]['height'] )
                return $_size;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

By default it is taking width 150 and height 150 which is passed like this `$w = 150, $h = 150`. And you have to use it like `the_dramatist_get_image_size_name(300, 300)`. Please keep it in mind that `$w` and `$h` takes integer value.

Comment: What if your medium size is set to 300x300 without hard crop, so the image being inspected might be 300x200 or 200x300?

Comment: As far I know, there is no rules of how you name your functions. It's a good practice to prefix your functions, but you can use whatever prefix you want. Use the namescpace `wpse_xxxx` if you want; don't use it if you don't want to. See http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/prefixing-function-names

Comment: It's checking the both dimensions of a single image. See here,  `if ( $w == get_option( "{$_size}_size_w" ) && $h == get_option( "{$_size}_size_h" ))` and here `if ( $w == $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ]['width'] && $h == $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ]['height']  )`. I don't think there is a problem. @AndyMacaulay-Brook

Comment: @cybmeta I couldn't see a reference but got told off by someone with a lot of rep for not doing it :-S

Comment: So it only returns true if _both_ the width and the height match exactly.

Comment: Exactly. As far I tested. But if you think you can make it better then you are most welcome. @AndyMacaulay-Brook